# Using ActiveRecord to query an aliased association with QueryMethod.references

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, alias

Does anyone know how to query an aliased association table with the `#references` method in ActiveRecord (Rails 4)? Is this the best way to approach filtering results on an aliased association?

The model with aliases:

```rb
class UserReadingLevel < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :assessor, class_name: "User", foreign_key: :assessor_id
  belongs_to :student, class_name: "User", foreign_key: :student_id
end
```

in console:

```rb
student = FactoryGirl.create :user, roles: ["student"]
teacher = FactoryGirl.create :user, roles: ["teacher"]
tutor = FactoryGirl.create :user, roles: ["tutor"]
rl1 = FactoryGirl.create :user_reading_level, assessor: teacher, student: student, reading_level: "c"
rl2 = FactoryGirl.create :user_reading_level, assessor: tutor, student: student, reading_level: "d"
```

the attempted query:

```rb
assessment = student.user_reading_levels.references(:assessors).where(assessor: { id: 2 })
```

the error message:

```
G::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "assessor"
LINE 1: ...WHERE "user_reading_levels"."student_id" = $1 AND "assessor"...
                                                             ^
: SELECT "user_reading_levels".* FROM "user_reading_levels"  WHERE "user_reading_levels"."student_id" = $1 AND "assessor"."id" = 2
```

This is the library method I'm trying to use, but it doesn't specify aliased tables:

[ActiveRecord::QueryMethods.references](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-references)s